# Добавил библиотеку JSON, при использовании Listener'a выдает ошибку

Tags: python, python-3.x

До того пока я не добавил json все работало нормально, теперь когда я пишу на своей тачке, например команду dir, скрипт крашиться, вот методы которые добавил:

```
def reliable_send(self, data):
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
    self.connection.send(json_data)

def reliable_receive(self):
    json_data = self.connection.recv(1024)
    return json.loads(json_data)
```

Ошибка которую выдаёт:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 34, in <module>
    my_listener.run()
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 30, in run
    result = self.execute_remotely(command)
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 24, in execute_remotely
    self.reliable_send(command.encode())
  File "/root/PycharmProjects/new1/listener/listener.py", line 16, in reliable_send
    json_data = json.dumps(data)
TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable
```

Comment: Нужно смотреть что у вас за data. Байты нельзя просто так преобразовать в json, можно только списки, словари, строки, числа.

Comment: @insolor Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне нужно декодировать байты в строку? return json.loads(json_data.decode()) верно, а потом уже передавать json?

Comment: Сначала нужно разобраться, что конкретно вы хотите сделать. Если вам нужно просто передать эти байты, потом получить их на другой стороне, то json не нужен вообще. Сейчас получается, что вы сначала что-то кодируете в байты, потом декодируете (чтобы положить в json), потом кодируете в json, еще раз кодируете в байты, на принимающей стороне все то же самое в обратном порядке в обратную сторону.

Comment: @insolor Json использую для того, чтобы к примеру файл txt читался в моём терминале. Я тестирую клиент > сервер. В дальнейшем хочу реализовать функции download и upload

Comment: `Json использую для того, чтобы к примеру файл txt читался в моём терминале.` - он не читается если передавать без json?

Comment: @insolor вот сейчас проверил, все работает без JSON'a, попробую написать свой код и реализовать дальнейшие функции, спасибо

Comment: @insolor у меня тогда ещё вопрос, как мне реализовать функцию передачи команд с моей основной машины, на локальную? Например команда "CD" не работает, в то время как команда "DIR" отображает файлы в директории, в которой лежит бэкдор, но я не могу передвигать по системе. У меня есть 2 кода https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1315459/%D0%9E%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%B1%D0%BA%D0%B0-typeerror-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable вот по этой теме, прочитав топики, я сделал так как указанно, но при полном коде, соединение держится, но команды не реализуются "[-] Error during command execution.",

Comment: @insolor "[-] Error during command execution." - выходит, так как я указал исключение, чтобы исключение не падало

Comment: Нужно смотреть что за исключение конкретно вылетает, так не понятно что там могло случиться.

Comment: @insolor если опускать команды и функции «upload, download”, в общем все функции которые указные в старом топике, ссылка которого я приложил, то у меня выходит ошибка TypeError: Object of type bytes is not JSON serializable. Я также указывал строку json_data = b’’. Я уверен что сама проблема кроется в необузданном JSON, возможно ли что это ещё из-за различий версий, потому что в моем курсе, скрипт пишется на Python2, я же использую 3, так как функционал проще, позже создам новый вопрос, где выложу 2 скрипта

Comment: @insolor кстати вот мой вопрос на зарубежном стаковер, там я как раз и выложил 2 скрипта https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850809/ive-issue-with-my-listener-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable-pytho